# Quadrilateral Inscribed angles calculation with one arc angle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying desperately to solve following problem. How can I solve it, the image and question is included in image

[image]

Comment: I don't see any need for the arc BC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\square ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $m\angle ADC + m\angle ABC = 180^\circ \implies m\angle ADC = 180^\circ - 100^\circ = 80^\circ$, using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Characterizations).